# How to resize the x-axis tick values in the heat map to fit within the window in a flexdashboard?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, flexdashboard

I have a problem where the x-axis values (the manufacturers listed on the heat map) are overlapping with each other due to the number of manufacturers in the dataset. Is there a way to dynamically change the size of these x-axis tick labels/values so they don't overlap with each other when using shiny/flexdashboard? What I mean by "dynamic" is for the size of the x-axis tick values (i.e. the manufacturers) to change based on the user's selection in the drop down. If there are other ways to deal with this problem other than dynamically resizing the x-axis tick values, I am open to it as well.

**Here is the data:**

```
structure(list(Toys = c("Slinky", "Slinky", "Slinky", "Slinky", 
"Slinky", "Slinky", "Tin Solider", "Tin Solider", "Tin Solider", 
"Tin Solider", "Tin Solider", "Tin Solider", "Hungry Hungry Hippo", 
"Hungry Hungry Hippo", "Hungry Hungry Hippo", "Hungry Hungry Hippo", 
"Hungry Hungry Hippo", "Hungry Hungry Hippo", "Bead Maze", "Bead Maze", 
"Bead Maze", "Bead Maze", "Bead Maze", "Bead Maze", "Hula Hoop", 
"Hula Hoop", "Hula Hoop", "Hula Hoop", "Hula Hoop", "Hula Hoop", 
"Kaleidoscope", "Kaleidoscope", "Kaleidoscope", "Kaleidoscope", 
"Kaleidoscope", "Kaleidoscope", "Pogo Stick", "Pogo Stick", "Pogo Stick", 
"Pogo Stick", "Pogo Stick", "Pogo Stick", "Jump N' Dunk Trampoline", 
"Jump N' Dunk Trampoline", "Jump N' Dunk Trampoline", "Jump N' Dunk Trampoline", 
"Jump N' Dunk Trampoline", "Jump N' Dunk Trampoline", "Play-Doh", 
"Play-Doh", "Play-Doh", "Play-Doh", "Play-Doh", "Play-Doh", "Mr. Potato Head", 
"Mr. Potato Head", "Mr. Potato Head", "Mr. Potato Head", "Mr. Potato Head", 
"Mr. Potato Head", "Corn Popper", "Corn Popper", "Corn Popper", 
"Corn Popper", "Corn Popper", "Corn Popper", "Let's Go Fishing", 
"Let's Go Fishing", "Let's Go Fishing", "Let's Go Fishing", "Let's Go Fishing", 
"Let's Go Fishing", "Operation", "Operation", "Operation", "Operation", 
"Operation", "Operation", "Ker Plunk", "Ker Plunk", "Ker Plunk", 
"Ker Plunk", "Ker Plunk", "Ker Plunk", "Jack-In-The-Box", "Jack-In-The-Box", 
"Jack-In-The-Box", "Jack-In-The-Box", "Jack-In-The-Box", "Jack-In-The-Box", 
"Xylophone", "Xylophone", "Xylophone", "Xylophone", "Xylophone", 
"Xylophone", "Chatter Phone", "Chatter Phone", "Chatter Phone", 
"Chatter Phone", "Chatter Phone", "Chatter Phone", "Jumbo Jacks", 
"Jumbo Jacks", "Jumbo Jacks", "Jumbo Jacks", "Jumbo Jacks", "Jumbo Jacks", 
"Rock 'em Sock 'em Robots", "Rock 'em Sock 'em Robots", "Rock 'em Sock 'em Robots", 
"Rock 'em Sock 'em Robots", "Rock 'em Sock 'em Robots", "Rock 'em Sock 'em Robots", 
"Silly Putty", "Silly Putty", "Silly Putty", "Silly Putty", "Silly Putty", 
"Silly Putty", "TinkerToy", "TinkerToy", "TinkerToy", "TinkerToy", 
"TinkerToy", "TinkerToy", "Silly Putty", "Silly Putty", "Silly Putty", 
"Silly Putty", "Silly Putty", "Silly Putty", "Red Wagon", "Red Wagon", 
"Red Wagon", "Red Wagon", "Red Wagon", "Red Wagon", "Magic 8 Ball", 
"Magic 8 Ball", "Magic 8 Ball", "Magic 8 Ball", "Magic 8 Ball", 
"Magic 8 Ball"), Manufacturer = c("Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer A", 
"Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer A", 
"Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", 
"Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", 
"Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", 
"Manufacturer D", "Manufacturer D", "Manufacturer D", "Manufacturer D", 
"Manufacturer D", "Manufacturer D", "Manufacturer E", "Manufacturer E", 
"Manufacturer E", "Manufacturer E", "Manufacturer E", "Manufacturer E", 
"Manufacturer G", "Manufacturer G", "Manufacturer G", "Manufacturer G", 
"Manufacturer G", "Manufacturer G", "Manufacturer H", "Manufacturer H", 
"Manufacturer H", "Manufacturer H", "Manufacturer H", "Manufacturer H", 
"Manufacturer I", "Manufacturer I", "Manufacturer I", "Manufacturer I", 
"Manufacturer I", "Manufacturer I", "Manufacturer J", "Manufacturer J", 
"Manufacturer J", "Manufacturer J", "Manufacturer J", "Manufacturer J", 
"Manufacturer K", "Manufacturer K", "Manufacturer K", "Manufacturer K", 
"Manufacturer K", "Manufacturer K", "Manufacturer L", "Manufacturer L", 
"Manufacturer L", "Manufacturer L", "Manufacturer L", "Manufacturer L", 
"Manufacturer M", "Manufacturer M", "Manufacturer M", "Manufacturer M", 
"Manufacturer M", "Manufacturer M", "Manufacturer N", "Manufacturer N", 
"Manufacturer N", "Manufacturer N", "Manufacturer N", "Manufacturer N", 
"Manufacturer O", "Manufacturer O", "Manufacturer O", "Manufacturer O", 
"Manufacturer O", "Manufacturer O", "Manufacturer P", "Manufacturer P", 
"Manufacturer P", "Manufacturer P", "Manufacturer P", "Manufacturer P", 
"Manufacturer Q", "Manufacturer Q", "Manufacturer Q", "Manufacturer Q", 
"Manufacturer Q", "Manufacturer Q", "Manufacturer R", "Manufacturer R", 
"Manufacturer R", "Manufacturer R", "Manufacturer R", "Manufacturer R", 
"Manufacturer S", "Manufacturer S", "Manufacturer S", "Manufacturer S", 
"Manufacturer S", "Manufacturer S", "Manufacturer T", "Manufacturer T", 
"Manufacturer T", "Manufacturer T", "Manufacturer T", "Manufacturer T", 
"Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer A", 
"Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", 
"Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", 
"Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", 
"Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer D", "Manufacturer D", 
"Manufacturer D", "Manufacturer D", "Manufacturer D", "Manufacturer D", 
"Manufacturer R", "Manufacturer R", "Manufacturer R", "Manufacturer R", 
"Manufacturer R", "Manufacturer R"), Price = c(5.99, 6.99, 7.99, 
9, 6, 5.54, 7, 9.99, 6.99, 6.75, 8, 7.99, 9.99, 7.99, 5.99, 8.99, 
10.99, 9.75, 9.99, 10.15, 8.99, 6.99, 5.99, 9.99, 9.99, 7.75, 
8.75, 9.95, 4.5, 5.54, 3.99, 4.5, 7.5, 8.95, 8.9, 6.99, 150.99, 
175.99, 170.99, 180.99, 190.99, 175, 310.64, 335.64, 360.64, 
385.64, 410.64, 435.64, 7.99, 8.99, 9.05, 9.1, 9.99, 10.15, 6.75, 
8.75, 7.75, 9.75, 6.75, 8.75, 10.35, 10.55, 11, 17, 17.75, 18, 
6.97, 7.05, 8.97, 9, 8.99, 6.99, 19.99, 21.15, 16.99, 17.99, 
18.99, 14.99, 14.96, 14.97, 15.15, 18.17, 19, 50, 6, 7, 8, 7, 
9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 11, 12, 9, 5, 6, 7, 7.5, 5, 5, 10.95, 9.95, 
9.99, 10.5, 10.95, 9.95, 28, 30, 28, 32, 27, 27.95, 5, 3, 4, 
5, 4, 3, 25, 25, 27, 29, 25.5, 28.5, 5.12, 4.95, 5, 4.5, 5.12, 
5, 15, 16, 16, 14.99, 15.5, 16, 5, 6.5, 5.5, 7.5, 6, 5), change = c(0, 
16.69449082, 14.30615165, 12.640801, -33.33333333, -7.666666667, 
0, 42.71428571, -30.03003003, -3.433476395, 18.51851852, -0.125, 
0, -20.02002002, -25.03128911, 50.08347245, 22.24694105, -11.28298453, 
0, 1.601601602, -11.42857143, -22.24694105, -14.30615165, 66.77796327, 
0, -22.42242242, 12.90322581, 13.71428571, -54.77386935, 23.11111111, 
0, 12.78195489, 66.66666667, 19.33333333, -0.558659218, -21.46067416, 
0, 16.55738791, -2.841070515, 5.848295222, 5.525167136, -8.372166082, 
0, 8.047901107, 7.44845668, 6.932120674, 6.482730007, 6.088057666, 
0, 12.51564456, 0.667408231, 0.552486188, 9.78021978, 1.601601602, 
0, 29.62962963, -11.42857143, 25.80645161, -30.76923077, 29.62962963, 
0, 1.93236715, 4.265402844, 54.54545455, 4.411764706, 1.408450704, 
0, 1.147776184, 27.23404255, 0.334448161, -0.111111111, -22.24694105, 
0, 5.802901451, -19.66903073, 5.885815185, 5.558643691, -21.06371775, 
0, 0.06684492, 1.20240481, 19.9339934, 4.56796918, 163.1578947, 
0, 16.66666667, 14.28571429, -12.5, 28.57142857, 11.11111111, 
0, 10, 9.090909091, -8.333333333, 9.090909091, -25, 0, 20, 16.66666667, 
7.142857143, -33.33333333, 0, 0, -9.132420091, 0.40201005, 5.105105105, 
4.285714286, -9.132420091, 0, 7.142857143, -6.666666667, 14.28571429, 
-15.625, 3.518518519, 0, -40, 33.33333333, 25, -20, -25, 0, 0, 
8, 7.407407407, -12.06896552, 11.76470588, -82.03508772, 0, 1.01010101, 
-10, 13.77777778, -2.34375, 0, 6.666666667, 0, -6.3125, 3.402268179, 
3.225806452, 0, 30, -15.38461538, 36.36363636, -20, -16.66666667
), Dates = c("1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", 
"9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", 
"7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", 
"5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "1/1/2021", 
"3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -144L))
```

**Here's the actual code:**

````
---
title: "Test"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(tidyquant)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(pins)
library(shiny)
library(httr)
library(XML)
library(DT)
library(plotly)
library(purrr)


test_data  <- #insert dput here

```


Sidebar {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}

selectInput("Toys",
            label = "Toys",
            choices = c("ALL",unique(sort(test_data$Toys))),
            selected = "ALL")

selectInput("Manufacturer",
                label = "Manufacturer",
                choices = c("ALL", test_data %>% 
                          dplyr::select(Manufacturer) %>% 
                          dplyr::arrange(Manufacturer)),
            selected = "ALL")
                  

dateRangeInput(inputId = "Dates",
               label = "Date Range",
               start = Sys.Date() %m+% years(-1),
               end = Sys.Date(),
               format = 'yyyy-mm')

```

Column 
-------------------------------------
```{r}
#Hides initial error messages
tags$style(type="text/css",
  ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
  ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
)

observe({
      # updateSelectInput(inputId = "Toys", 
      #                 choices = test_data[test_data$Manufacturer==input$Manufacturer,
      #                                     "Toys"])
      updateSelectInput(inputId = "Manufacturer", 
                        choices = test_data[test_data$Toys ==input$Toys, 
                                            "Manufacturer"] %>% 
                          append('ALL', after = 0))
  
})


Toys_reactive <- reactive({ 
  
      test_data[(input$Manufacturer == "ALL" |
                                    test_data$Manufacturer == input$Manufacturer) & 
                                   (input$Toys == "ALL" | 
                                      test_data$Toys == input$Toys),,drop = FALSE]
    })

chart_height <- reactive({Toys_reactive() %>%
        dplyr::filter(!is.na(Dates)) %>%
        dplyr::select(Manufacturer) %>%
        unique %>%
        nrow * 130})

 output$plot <- renderPlotly({
       p <- Toys_reactive() %>% 
        dplyr::filter(!is.na(Dates)) %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x = Dates, y = Price, text = paste(paste0("Price: $", sprintf("%.2f", Price)),"<br> Date: ", Dates), group = Manufacturer)) + 
          geom_point(size = 1.5) + 
          geom_line() + 
         facet_wrap(~Manufacturer, scales = "free", ncol = 1) +
          theme_bw() + 
           theme(
            title = element_text(colour='black'),
             axis.title.x = element_blank(),
            axis.title.y = element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_text(size = rel(0.85)),
            panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey70", size = 0.1),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.border = element_blank(),
            panel.spacing = unit(0.45,"cm")
           ) #ensuring that plots render properly
       ggplotly(p, height = chart_height(), tooltip = "text", xaxis = list(automargin = T)) %>% layout(margin=list(b=25))
        
     })
    #Renders the plot above with the proper height
    renderUI({
      plotlyOutput("plot", height = "100%")
    })
    
```

{.tabset .tabset-fade}
-------------------------------------

### Heat Map

```{r}
renderPlotly({p <- ggplot(Toys_reactive() %>% 
                            dplyr::group_by(Toys, Manufacturer) %>% 
                            dplyr::summarize(change = sum(change, na.rm = TRUE)),
                  aes(x = Manufacturer, y = Toys)) + 
                    geom_tile(aes(fill = change)) +
                    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
                          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                          axis.title.y = element_blank(), legend.key.size = unit(0.5,                            'cm')) +
                    scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "B", direction = -1)

    ggplotly(p) %>% layout(autosize = T)
  })
````

**Here's a picture of what I mean:**
[image]

*Please note, this is only a test dataset so the heat map does look funky. It's more to provide a illustrative example.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by adjusting your plot function to have its formatting change with the number of categories it needs to show. Here, I make the size of the axis text adjust to the number of categories.

```
library(tidyverse)
df_var_size <- function(x_cat = 32) {
  mtcars %>%
    rownames_to_column("car") %>%
    slice(1:x_cat) -> mtcars_sized
    
  mtcars_sized %>%
  ggplot(aes(car, mpg)) +
    geom_point() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
      angle = 60, hjust = 1, size = pmin(10, 200 / length(unique(mtcars_sized$car)))))
}
```

Results. Note how when the categories grow to 30, the text gets smaller. I use `pmin` so that the text doesn't get any bigger than 10 when there are few categories.

```
df_var_size(10)
```

[image]

```
df_var_size(20)
```

[image]

```
df_var_size(30)
```

[image]